# Logic between table entries

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form with a:

- first table with products and categories which are free typed (e.g. Category Fruit, line 1 product entry apples, line 2 oranges)
- second table where clients enter email addresses for suppliers of each category (2 columns - supplier email and category)

Is it possible to force the categories in the second table to be in line with the categories in the first table (e.g. if the client enters "fruit" as category in table 1 "cars" as a category in table 2, "cars" will be rejected)

Comment: Hi! Please submit a support request: https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/ and our support team can take a closer look at your particular form!